# unable to load collection view cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview

I am able to load the collection view but unable to load the cell.below is my code I'm using.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

   static NSString *identifier = @"reuseCell";
    [self.view_dashboard registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class]
            forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"reuseCell"];

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

   recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];

    recipeImageView.image= [UIImage imageNamed:[dashBoard_img objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Put this line `[self.view_dashboard registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"reuseCell"];` outside of `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, you can add it in `viewDidAppear`

Comment: have register nib file?

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint? Does cellForItemAtIndexPath: get called? You don't need to register the class every time for each cell. You only need to call this once elsewhere in your UIViewController.

Comment: yes i added above line but,we are unable to loading cell.@ viral

Comment: have you implemented datasource protocols?... also.. have you set your collectionview datasource delegate to be the viewcontroller?.. also check return value for : numberOfSectionsInCollectionView and numberOfItemsInSection

Comment: Yes i did, its working now, don't know what went wrong just deleted everything related collection view controller  from story board and recreated cell.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be anything particularly wrong with your code.

Loading a cell in a collection view requires more work than just this single method.

I would start explaining further, but I would just be reading the docs to you.  Instead, have a read of the Apple Documentation for yourself.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012177-CH1-SW4